# Why doesn't VS autocomplete when I am using templates?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, autocomplete

I am working on some data structures in C++ using templates and I ran to some problems.I am implementing a HashTable using chaining and I also implemented a Linked List.The first problem I ran was a Linking Error with my template definitions which I solved by including the `.cpp` file where the declaration was.

Now I ran to another issue and I am not sure if it is a problem related to templates or maybe VS settings.First of all,building the project doesn't update it unless I save and compile my entry point for some reason.I read some issues and the settings seem ok.
The most important issue I ran into was that in my `Hashtable.cpp` file I have autocomplete issues regarding *ONLY* anything related to my `List` class.

For example :
I used `List<T> **arr` in my `Hashtable` class and whenever I try to use any of the list methods e.g. `arr[1]->insert(100)` not only it doesn't autocomplete,but it says the the method belongs to   as I show to the screenshot below.
The declarations look like this : 
`Hashtable.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "Log.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

`Hashtable.cpp`:
`#include "Hashtable.h"`

And my list class doesnt have anything special included besides `iostream` etc

I want to point out that the code doesn't autocomplete but It works,it runs the correct methods but It is really uncomfortable and annoying to work with.Also I have worries that it might not work in another computer which really matters to me.
Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

The screenshot I [mentioned](http://prntscr.com/nstoe4)

Comment: Dependent types are hard to autocomplete

Comment: @Galik Yeah that would actually be a lesser headache I didn't consider.It wouldn't be hard to implement.I am not sure it will solve the autocompletion stuff though.

Comment: @YosokuDenkai I just realized your not using `std::list` but your own class, but its worth doing it that way. Not intended as a solution to the autocomplete problem.

Comment: VS should autocomplete in this scenario. It works for me for `std::string` and `std::vector` (and for my templates) so I don't see a reason your template should not be auto-completed. @GuillaumeRacicot note in his scenario it is not dependent type. Hopefully in C++20 concepts will become handy to autocomplete depending types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autocomplete gets confused by templates. Keep in mind that when a compiler is compiling temnplated code, it knows what the template parameters are going to be. In contrast, when you're writing code in a templated class, the autocomplete system doesn't know what the parameter is going to be.

For instance, if you have `List<T> **arr` and `List` has an `insert()` method, is `arr[1]->insert(100)` valid? Maybe! or maybe not. There might be a specialization of `List` for a particular `T`, which doesn't have an `insert` method.

Additionally, autocomplete systems tend to be as much of an art as a science, since they have to run at interactive speed, and need to be robust to syntax errors earlier in the code. Templates put them at their worst, since the syntax and grammar of templates is considerably trickier to get right than other areas of C++, so when working with heavily templated code you'll tend to see autocomplete acting its worst.

When working with heavily templated code, I have on occasion "de-templated" the code while working on it simply to help the compiler out. Recent versions of VS will actually help you with this: templates that the compiler finds confusing may (usually, but not always, and I'm not sure why) offer you the opportunity to help it out:

[image]

If you click on that `<T>` icon, it'll ask you to give it an example of a type you might instantiate it with, and use that type for autocomplete. That can significantly improve its effectiveness.

Comment: I actually didn't know that,Its my first time working heavily with templates besides simple function etc

Answer (score 4):

Newer version of Visual Studio have a feature where you can select concrete types to instantiate a given template with for the purpose of having autocompletion in it:

[image]

In VS2017 you have to type these in manually. In VS2019, you can select from a list of actual instantiations of the template you're in.

Without these hints, Intellisense has no chance of knowing what `Hashtable<T>` has in terms of members - you could have specialized it any number of times, `arr` could have any type, and `clear()` could return all kinds of things depending on `T`. Any suggestions it gives could be wrong for a different set of template arguments...

Comment: I notice the Visual Assist icon. Is this a builtin feature or Visual Asssist?

Comment: It is builtin (and a major reason for me not to use the Visual Assist "intellisense" but the builtin one).

Comment: I havent upgraded to VS2019 yet,I guess its worth my time.Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you confirm if you are using Microsoft Template Intellisense feature and is enabled?
2. Some of these Autocomplete related issues have been resolved/fixed in the version 15.8-preview5 - are you using an older version of VS?
3. If the code works, I think you need to make sure your VS Code environment is fixed with all the necessary tools are in place.
4. Portability of your C++ Code should not be a concern as long as your Compiler Environment and all the dependencies are preserved in the right configuration or a Makefile as is necessary.

-SJ

Comment: 1 - I cant really confirm that?I am not sure what it is since Im using templates heavily for the first time.I guess it should be what the default is.
2 - I am using the latest 2017 version,not the VS2019 one
3 - I double checked that and it is fine.

Comment: 1. Download the latest Visual Studio 2018 or 2019 as may be the case for you. To disable/enable the feature, go to Tools > Options > C/C++ > Advanced > IntelliSense > Enable Template IntelliSense.
2. You can refer to more details about the Intellisense feature here
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-c-template-intellisense-populates-based-on-instantiations-in-your-code/#