# c++ type container that is code completion friendly?

Tags: c++, c++20, clion, c++-concepts, code-completion

Consider [the following code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/dGsohWeW3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>  

template<typename T>
concept Traits = requires(typename T::DispatcherT a, typename T::MsgT& b)
{
    { a.handleMsg(b) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

struct MsgOne {
    int first{1};
};
struct MsgTwo {
    int first{10};
    double second{100.5};
};

struct DispatcherOne {
    void handleMsg(MsgOne& msg) { std::cout << "One: " << msg.first << '\n'; }
};
struct DispatcherTwo {
    void handle(MsgTwo msg) { std::cout << "Two: " << msg.first << " " << msg.second << '\n'; }
};

struct TraitsOne {
    using DispatcherT = DispatcherOne;
    using MsgT = MsgOne;
};

struct TraitsTwo {
    using DispatcherT = DispatcherTwo;
    using MsgT = MsgTwo;
};

template <Traits T> 
struct Driver {
    using DispatcherT = typename T::DispatcherT;
    using MsgT = typename T::MsgT;
    void handleMsg(MsgT &msg) { 
        dispatcher.handleMsg(msg); 
        //dispatcher. <- code completion fails to offer handleMsg(..)
    }
    DispatcherT dispatcher;
};

int main() {
    Driver<TraitsOne> driver{};
    MsgOne msg{};
    driver.handleMsg(msg);
}
```

the problem that i have here is that Clion IDE (v2022.2) (with clangd(v13) as LSP) does not offer code completion on an instance of `DispatcherT` inside of `Driver<Traits T>` template.  Restricting the template parameter with a simpler concept such as

```
template<typename T>
concept Traits = requires(T a, MsgOne& b)
{
    { a.handleMsg(b) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};
```

works beautifully
[image]
but with the more complex `Traits`, code completion is lost.  My question is: what would be an alternative way of defining a container of types that is code-completion friendly?  I have thought about `std::tuple<>` but haven't tried it since accessing the types might be a bit cumbersome (imho). It seems Visual Studio [is offering  intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293251/why-doesnt-vs-autocomplete-when-i-am-using-templates) but I am constrained to use clangd.  Any ideas and critisisms are welcome!

Comment: You really should tailor your code in such a structural way to code-completion. Write code that makes sense and is self-documenting, and let the various tools you use mature in their own time.

Comment: @NicolBolas thank you for your comment.  I fully agree that code clarity and correctness supercedes concerns about support from tooling.  However, i found myself in a situation where one of my (more senior) colleagues is heavily married to code-completion capabilities of the CLion IDE.  One of the recent refactorings to our code base involved moving from preprocessor-based polymorphism to static polymorphism via templates.  This broke code-completion and now we have an issue.  It's in the best interests of good team spirit that we get the best of both worlds.